# "Customized clothes" or "custom-made clothes"

Tags: expressions

I make personalized clothes and I want to specify on my web site but I do not know how to express my self, should I say Customized clothes? or custom-made clothes? or do you have another option that may help?

I understand that "customized" could express modify  so I do not know if it is a good option for my specific situation

Comment: *tailor-made*....

Answer (score 0):

There's an American English-British English split on this.

American English: custom-tailored or [tailored](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tailored)

British English: [bespoke](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bespoke)

Both mean

> custom-made

particularly in regards to clothing

Comment: I'm seeing bespoke more and more in the US, though, so it would be understood here, too. But I'd argue that "tailored" means more like "fitted" rather than made from scratch to fit you.

Answer (score 0):

Customized and Custom-made mean slightly different things. Custom-made means that your product is made to order. Customized means that a person can personalize their order. If you wanted to convey both you could say "Customizable and Made-to-order" or even just "Custom-made and Customizable" (yes customizable is barely a word but that's not important because even if people look at it and think "is that a word?" that is actually beneficial, many psychology exparaments have shown that basically anything that makes your business stand out or makes people think back on it is positive for business)